# Need to pass color to CSS with variable js

Tags: javascript, css, jscolor

I have code which passes generated background-color to CSS in `<style>` tags with variable so I could copy it to buffer and I need to do the same with text color. I use a color picker http://jscolor.com/. I tried to duplicate the same logic with different names but it didn't work. I need to be able to copy this CSS code to clipboard with actual font color too.

```
    <script>

  function copyToClipboard(element) {
  let currentColor = $("#valueInput").val();
  let currentStyle = $(element).text();

  let newStyle = currentStyle.replace('--placeholder', "#"+currentColor);


  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(newStyle).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();


}

function update(jscolor) {

       document.getElementById('button_cont').style.color = '#' + jscolor;


    }

</script>


<style type="text/css">


    #button_cont {
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
 background-color: --placeholder;
padding: 10px;
/* border: 1px solid #ffffff; */
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;

} 
</style>



 <a href="#" id="button_cont" >Call to action</a>  

  <button class="jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput', styleElement:'button_cont'}" >
    Generate color
</button> 

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('style')">Copy CSS</button>
```

I tried this

```
<script>
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  let currentColor = $("#valueInput").val();
  let currentStyle = $(element).text();

  let newStyle = currentStyle.replace('--placeholder', "#"+currentColor);

  let currenttextColor = $("#button_cont").val();
  let currenttextStyle = $(element).text();

  let newtextStyle = currenttextStyle.replace('--placeholdtext', "#"+currenttextColor);


  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(newStyle).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();

  var $tempt = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($tempt);
  $tempt.val(newtextStyle).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $tempt.remove();
}

</script>
```

Comment: _Show us_ what you tried.

Comment: Updated what I tried

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  // input value
  let currentColor = $("#valueInput").val();

  // style block content
  let currenttextStyle = $(element).text();

  // replace the style block content with the input color value
  let newtextStyle = currenttextStyle.replace('--placeholdtext', "#" + currentColor);

  // create an input field, set the new style content and execute copy to hold the content
  var $tempt = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($tempt);
  $tempt.val(newtextStyle).select();
    try { 
        success = document.execCommand("copy", false, null);
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e)
    }
    //alert(success)
  $tempt.remove();
}
```

The key requirement is the function should be triggered by user action like click, otherwise, it will be failed and the 'success' flag is false.

Comment: Could you please update how it should look like I can't make it work?

Comment: I edited it like this `let currenttextColor = $('style').find('#button_cont').length == 0;
  let currenttextStyle = $('style').html();` but it doesn't work

Comment: var css = element.html();
            var pos = css.indexOf('#button_cont');
            var colorPos = css.indexOf('color:', pos + 1);
            var colorEnd = css.indexOf(';', colorPos); currenttextColor = css.substring(colorPos + 6, colorEnd); // Only for the text value. Your idea need to be sorted further

Comment: Can't sort it out still

Comment: After all, I changed your codes and tested them locally. It's OK now.

Comment: Thanks but It passes background color to font color but I found that color can be passed with the help of this `<input type="text" class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor);" style="display: none;" value="" />` and  assigning class .jscolor to currenttextColor `let currenttextColor = $(".jscolor").val();` but it doesn't recognize the automatically changing color, must be placed something in `value=" "` of the `<input>` and works only without the bg js code.

Comment: And don't forget to put this to the script: `function update(jscolor) {
      
       document.getElementById('button_cont').style.color = '#' + jscolor;

    } `

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me, check out this snippet; what's wrong with it?

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  let currentColor = $("#valueInput").val();
  let currentStyle = $(element).text();

  let newStyle = currentStyle.replace('--placeholder', "#" + currentColor);

  let currenttextColor = $("#button_cont").val();
  let currenttextStyle = $(element).text();

  let newtextStyle = currenttextStyle.replace('--placeholdtext', "#" + currenttextColor);


  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(newStyle).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();

  var $tempt = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($tempt);
  $tempt.val(newtextStyle).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $tempt.remove();
}
```

```css
#button_cont {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: --placeholder;
  padding: 10px;
  /* border: 1px solid #ffffff; */
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="button_cont">Call to action</a>

<button class="jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput', styleElement:'button_cont'}">
    Generate color
</button>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('style')">Copy CSS</button>
```

Comment: Now with this code on my site it doesn't copy it at all and here in the sandbox it copies color: always #333; and background-color: --placeholder;

Comment: I missed `}` in my code and now it copy the css but without the colors